# Extracting string after x hyphens using oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I would like to extract Customer codes using Oracle database functionality.
Example 00001128163 in the 2) example below and nulls otherwise. I have several patterns, like below.

1) 07112011-900-46800-30-1-90-72190-75020-1-0--
2) 07112011-900-46800-30-1-92-72137-74362-1-0-00001128163-0
3) 07112011-900-46800-30-1-1600-85551-89013-100-0--

Comment: Try `regexp_substr(col, '-(\d{11})-\d+$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('123-345-434-346', '-([^-]*)', 1, 2, 'i', 1) from dual;
```

The "2" is the position after the first one so 434 in this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  Very helpful to pick up the concept of 11 th field from Hyphen from your answers.

I  tried 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(F.col,'[^-]+', 1, 11) from table F
and it works graet!!